# Fluid Grid - Need to add a link to on an image

Tags: html, css, asp.net

a novice here looking for some assistance.

I have a fluid grid inside a container. The grid has a number of columns that contain images. Most of the images are static but I need to add hyper links to a couple of the images. However, when I add in code that actives a link, it is placing the image outside the defined column. Could anyone advise what I need to do?

```
<div class="container">  
    <div class="section group">
            <div class="col span_1_of_4">
                <asp:Image ID=".." run at="server" style="width:100%" Image1Url="~/Images/.../...." />
            </div>
            <div class="col span_2_of_4">
                <asp:Image ID="..." run at="server" style="width:100%" Image1Url="~/Images/...." />
            </div>
            <div class="col span_3_of_4">
                <asp:Image ID="..." run at="server" style="width:100%" Image1Url="~/Images/.../..." />
                <asp:Image ID="..." run at="server" style="width:100%" Image1Url="~/Images/Shared/..." />
            </div>
            <div class="col span_4_of_4">
      <a href="https://twitter.com/Careers" class=".1span_4_of_4 a" target="_blank"><asp:Image ID="img1Twitter" run at="server" style="width:100%" Image1Url="~/Images/Shared/..." /></a>
    </div>
      </div>
</div>
```

C.S.S

```
container {
    margin: 0 auto;
    position:absolute;
    width:100%;
    top: 35%;
    height: 150%;
    padding: 0;
    left: 5%;
}
/*  SECTIONS  */
.section {
    clear: both;
    padding: 0 pixels;
    margin: 0 pixels;
}

/*  COLUMN*/
.col {
    display: block;
    float:left;
    margin: 1% 0 1% 1.6%;
    background-size: cover;
}
.col:first-child { margin-left: 0; }

/*  GROUPING  */
.group:before,
.group:after { content:""; display:table; }
.group:after { clear:both;}
.group { zoom:1;  }

/*  GRID OF FOUR  */
.span_4_of_4 { max-width: 100%; display: block; }
.span_3_of_4 { width: 20%; }
.span_2_of_4 { width: 27%; }
.span_1_of_4 { width: 20%; }


.span_4_of_4 a { max-width: 100%; display: block; } 
.img1Twitter {width: 19%; display: block;}
```

Comment: Can you please show the screenshot of output ?

Comment: I would have to change all the images for privacy reasons. Using the grid of four code above the first three images display correctly in their columns. However, image 4 is supposed to be a link but when I put in code to make it a link before the asp image id code, the image moves outside the grid. If I switch this line around then the image appears in the grid but the image is not clickable,

Comment: It might not be because of the CSS, this could be because of the HTML markup you're getting after adding the link. What is the HTML markup you're getting in the end ?

Comment: I've added the HTML Alok, best format I could.

Comment: Do you have styles defined for hyperlink in your CSS files ?

Comment: No, just what I have in the CSS above.

Comment: .span_4_of_4 img { max-width: 100%; display: block; } try adding this style to CSS.

Comment: No luck,  its still outside the grid.

Comment: The hyperlink must be the issue, when I remove this code it fits.

Comment: .span_4_of_4 a { max-width: 100%; display: block; } Try this to prevent hyperlink not to exceed size of column. Also Can you inspect element the grid section from the page and send the minimal HTML code you can show ?

Comment: Hi Alok, the code I pasted above is really it in a nutshell. I now have this for column 4 <div class="col span_4_of_4">
    <a href="https://twitter.com/..." class=".span_4_of_4 a" target="_blank"><asp:Image ID="imgTwitter" runat="server" style="width:100%" ImageUrl="~/Images/Shared/....jpg" /></a>
        </div>

Comment: /*  GRID OF FOUR  */
.span_4_of_4 { max-width: 100%; display: block; }
.span_3_of_4 { width: 20%; }
.span_2_of_4 { width: 27%; }
.span_1_of_4 { width: 20%; }

Comment: .imgTwitter {width: 19%; display: block;}

Comment: Your code should create any problem with the layout I think.  Does this class have any role in the styles ? " .1span_4_of_4 a " ? Remove "style="width:100%" from the ASP:image element.

Comment: When I remove the <a h1ref ...</a> the image displays fine in the grid and the sizing is fine. Adding the link in seems to disassociate it from the 4th column and it displays in the middle of the page.

Comment: If you share a screenshot by hiding privacy things or can simulate the same in jsFiddle I can help your properly with you question.